# Change a label react-materialize

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, stylesheet, materialize

I'm using react-materialize and I want to modify the default label of an Input using an stylesheet

```
    <Input s={6} l={3} label="Todos" type="select" defaultValue=''>
```

How could I get it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by modify the default label? As in change `label="Todos"` to something else?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I want to add style.

Comment: What kind of style are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `labelClassName` prop:

```
<Input labelClassName="class-here" s={6} l={3} ...>
       ^^^
```